# Binary numbers with leading zeros

Tags: c++, binary, leading-zero

I've been working on an assignment where I've to use bitwise operators to (OR, AND, or NOT )

the Program has a fixed 4X4 matrix and the user suppose to enter a query to the program ANDing two BINARY numbers, ORing them ...etc

the problem is the "zero leading" binary numbers for example:0111 are shown with value 73 
even when I manage to cout it with setfill() and setw() 
I can't perform the bitwise operation on the actual binary value!

N.B: I've tried strings instead of ints but the bitwise operation still doesn't apply.

For Example:

if I want to AND two binary values let's say 
int x=1100 and int y=0100 in another int z
z=x&y;

the result suppose to be 0100
But the result that appears is 64

which also the result that appears if I tried to print y to the screen

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int Matrix[4][4]={{1,1,0,0},{1,1,0,1},{1,1,0,1},{0,1,0,0}};
    string Doc[4]={"Doc1","Doc2","Doc3","Doc4"};
    string Term[4]={"T1","T2","T3","T4"};

    cout << "THE MATRIX IS:"<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        cout<<"\t"<<Doc[i];
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    for(int row=0; row<4;row++)
    {
        cout<<Term[row]<<"\t";
        for(int col=0;col<4;col++)
        {
            cout<<Matrix[row][col]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    int term1=1100;
    cout<<"\nTerm1= "<<term1;
    int term2=1101;
    cout<<"\nTerm2= "<<term2;
    int term3=1101;
    cout<<"\nTerm3= "<<term3;
    int term4=0100;
    cout<<"\nTerm4= "<<setfill('0')<<setw(4)<<term4;


    int Q=term1&term4;
    cout<<"\n Term1 and Term4 ="<<Q;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post code.  Also, numeric literals that start with `0` are `octal` in C++, not binary.  So `73` is the decimal equivalent of octal `111`.

Comment: The manipulator `std::dec` should prevent octal interpretation.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It seems `0111` gets parsed as octal number. Make sure the stream is set to use a known base. You'll read an integer with that base and decide the bunary value from there (I don't think streams support direct input of binary values). Alternatively use `std::bitset<4>`.

Comment: `int term1=1100;` -- This sets `term1` to `1100` (one thousand, one hundred).

Comment: @keith thompson I know but yet the ANDING of the terms comes correctly except for those with leading zero

Comment: @Rawan.S: Only by coincidence. `1100 & 1101 == 1100`, but `1100 & 1111 == 1092`. (All the numbers are decimal.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Thank you so much at least now I'm not confused anymore :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question still not clear. You have said you have 4x4 matrix, what type of matrix or 2D array is it? So maybe you can elaborate more.

Regarding dealing with binaries, what students usually confuse about, is that if you are using integer variables, you can use bitwise manipulation over these variables and the result will still be read as an integer format. And if you happen to seek seeing what is happening during the bitwise manipulation and visualize the process, you can always use `bitset` object as follow.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main() {
    int a = 7, b = a>>3, c = a<<2;

    std::cout << "a = " << std::bitset<8>(a)  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b = " << std::bitset<8>(b)  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c = " << std::bitset<8>(c) << std::endl;
}
```

Which should print

```
00000111
00000000
00011100
```

So play around with your variables and then visualize them as binaries using `bitset` is the best way to teach you how HEX, OCT, DEC, and BIN representation works.

And by the way if you are reading 73 as an integer, then this memory address stores `0100 1001` as binary if it's unsigned, and `111` as Octal which is base 8 number representation. See http://coderstoolbox.net/number/

Best of luck

Answer (score 2):

When you write `0111` in your code the compiler will assume it's octal since octal numbers start with zero. If you wrote `111` it would be decimal.

C++14 added binary literal prefix so you can write `0b111` to get what you want.

Comment: It doesn't work ... is there a specific library that I should include ?

Comment: @Rawan.S No, but your compiler needs to support C++14